# Solving the same MIP model with benders annotations twice throws an error in Cplex in python

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I am using Docplex in Python to solve a MIP. The model has benders annotations on it.

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
mdl = (create the MIP model with benders annotations)
mdl.solve(log_output=True)
```

The previous code runs with no problem at all. However, if a solve the model again

```
mdl.solve(log_output=True)
```

I get **CPLEX Error  1200: Index is outside range of valid values.** If a remove the annotations, I can re-solve the model without any problem.

Any ideas on how to handle this situation?

note: I am solving several similar models (with the same structure, just different parameters) but I cannot afford to build a new model every time since creating the model is time-consuming.